# how to change the color of hamburger icon in bootstrap 5

Tags: toggle, hamburger-menu

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
            <img class="nav-img" src="images/amd-white.svg" alt="">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="#navbarSupportedContent">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href=""></a>
                <div class="nav2"></div>
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <div class="nav2">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <div class="dropdown show">
                                <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                PRODUCT
                                </a>                      
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>                         
                        </li> 
                    </div>                  
                    <div class="nav2">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <div class="dropdown show">
                                <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                SOLUTION
                                </a>                      
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </div>                   
                    <div class="nav2">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <div class="dropdown show">
                                <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                SHOP
                                </a>                      
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                        </li> 
                    </div>                    
                    <div class="nav2">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <div class="driver">DRIVERS & SUPPORT</div>                            
                        </li> 
                    </div>                    
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question, You can add these bg classes to toggler button and the icon span to change its color, like this:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto bg-danger" 
                type="button" 
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#nav1">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon my-toggler bg-info">
          </span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the bootstrap icon by using CSS. To change the color replace the values of the "stroke". Currently the value is "stroke='rgba%283, 152, 158, 0.75%29'". The color is 3,152,158.

```
.navbar-toggler-icon
{
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba%283, 152, 158, 0.75%29' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='4' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}
```